# Как сделать передвижение картинки на определённое расстояние каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlabel, qpushbutton

Как сделать мини 'движок', чтобы управлять расположением картинкой.

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn1.setText("Вперед")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(450, 1000)
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("Назад")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn2.move(450, 1500)
        
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(800, 800)
        self.lbl1.move(220, 100)
        self.show()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И сделать как например тут:

```
x = 10
while True:
    a = input("Введите 'вперёд'")
    if a == "Вперёд":
        x += 1
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                          # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)                         # !!! +++
        
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("<-- Влево")
# ???                                                                 ------> v
#        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(100, 400)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Влево"))
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("Вправо -->")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn2.move(500, 400)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Вправо"))
        
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(centralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.move(300, 20)
        
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(centralWidget)
        self.spinBox.setRange(5, 20)
        self.spinBox.setValue(7)
        self.spinBox.resize(100, 30)
        self.spinBox.move(400, 560)        

    def on_clicked(self, text):
        print(f'{text}')  
        if text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x-self.spinBox.value() if x-self.spinBox.value() > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)            
        elif text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width() 
            x = x+self.spinBox.value() \
                if x+self.spinBox.value() < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y) 
            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(900, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А как сделать, что бы оно меняло местоположение на 100 пикселей и что бы не нужно было указывать на сколько пикселей двигать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                          # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)                         # !!! +++
        
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("<-- Влево")
# ???                                                                 ------> v
#        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(100, 400)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Влево"))
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("Вправо -->")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn2.move(500, 400)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Вправо"))
        
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(centralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.move(300, 20)
        
        '''
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(centralWidget)
        self.spinBox.setRange(5, 20)
        self.spinBox.setValue(7)
        self.spinBox.resize(100, 30)
        self.spinBox.move(400, 560) 
        '''
        self.num = 100 
        

    def on_clicked(self, text):
        print(f'{text}')  
        if text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x-self.num if x-self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)            
        elif text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width() 
            x = x+self.num \
                if x+self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y) 
            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(900, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы оно меняло местоположение на 100 пикселей и что бы не нужно было указывать на сколько пикселей двигать?

Comment: @TFader я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @TFader что не так?

Comment: Извиняюсь, отходил, все так, это решает мою проблему, благодарю!